# Sumar columnas pares de una tabla en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con 10 columnas como la de la imagen y necesito sumar individualmente solo aquellas columnas que son pares, es decir, c2, c4, c6, c8 y c10, de manera que me devuelva una tabla con dos columnas: el nombre de la columna (c2, c3...) y la suma de cada una de ellas. Entiendo que es necesario despivotar cada columna, pero me pierdo un poco con este tema. ¿Me podéis explicar cómo poder hacer esto? Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con sumar individualmente? ¿Sumar todos los valores de cada columna y mostrar cada uno en una fila?

Comment: Hola Luis, el resultado que busco es el de la respuesta de abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma más sencilla y versátil de hacer `unpivot` a las tablas y es mediante el uso del operador `APPLY` junto con los constructores de tablas `VALUES`.

La forma más sencilla de escribirlo es así

```
SELECT up.columna,
       SUM(up.valor) valor
FROM #Prueba
CROSS APPLY( VALUES ( 1, 'c2' , c2 ),
                    ( 2, 'c4' , c4 ),
                    ( 3, 'c6' , c6 ),
                    ( 4, 'c8' , c8 ),
                    ( 5, 'c10', c10))up(orden, columna, valor)
GROUP BY up.columna, up.orden
ORDER BY up.orden;
```

Usamos `CROSS APPLY` que funcionaría igual que el `OUTER APPLY` puesto que vamos a tener valores por todas las filas. En este caso estamos haciendo referencias a las columnas pares para poner una en cada fila y asignamos un orden y un nombre a cada fila para referenciar a cada columna.

Sin embargo, para optimizar la consulta es mejor hacer la sumatoria primero y luego convertir las columnas en filas.

```
SELECT up.columna,
       up.valor
FROM (
        SELECT SUM( c2 ) AS c2 ,
               SUM( c4 ) AS c4 ,
               SUM( c6 ) AS c6 ,
               SUM( c8 ) AS c8 ,
               SUM( c10) AS c10
        FROM #Prueba) p
CROSS APPLY( VALUES ( 1, 'c2' , c2 ),
                    ( 2, 'c4' , c4 ),
                    ( 3, 'c6' , c6 ),
                    ( 4, 'c8' , c8 ),
                    ( 5, 'c10', c10))up(orden, columna, valor)
ORDER BY up.orden;
```

Aunque el código es más extenso, es más fácil de procesar la consulta.

Comment: Gracias. Era justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 2):

Lo solucioné de este modo. Ya me decís cómo lo veis.

```
select columnas, suma from (
select columnas,
       sum(valor)suma, 
       row_number() over(order by(cast(substring(columnas,2,len(columnas)-1) as int)))linea 
from columnas
unpivot(
    valor for columnas in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10)
)t1
group by columnas
)t2
where 
     linea%2=0
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se podría reducir o alguien lo haría de otro modo?

Comment: Esta solución sería más eficiente si en el unpivot solo incluyes las columnas que quieres.

Comment: Ya, pero el ejercicio no era ese. El SQL debe ser capaz de discriminar qué columnas son pares o no, de ahí que se haga un cálculo adicional.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar directamente unpivot sobre las columnas y realizar la operación.

```
Create Table #temp (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int, c7 int, c8 int, c9 int, c10 int);
Insert into #temp (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10)
values
(85,10,25,87,69,22,90,89,96,50),
(54,50,90,88,30,91,5,46,37,44),
(30,10,24,53,8,11,1,16,80,61),
(44,1,20,66,4,7,62,88,70,57),
(65,50,100,50,97,18,90,27,46,75);
```

Sobre ese conjunto de datos.

```
Select upv.columna, sum(upv.valor) as valor  
from #temp
unpivot (valor for columna in (c2,c4,c6,c8,c10))upv 
group by upv.columna;
```

[image: Result]

De los comentarios que deberían de estar en la pregunta.

Si necesitas evaluar que las columnas sean pares, puedes aplicar en vez de un numerador, un case para comprobar si lo son o no y ejecutar en ese caso.

```
SELECT Sum(VALOR) AS VALOR
     , COLUMNA
       fROM (
              Select upv.columna
                   , upv.valor as valor
                   , CASE
                         WHEN
                     Cast(SubString(columna, 2, Len(columna) - 1) AS int) % 2 = 0 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                     END AS PAR
                     from temp1 unpivot(valor for columna in(c1
                                                           , c2
                                                           , c3
                                                           , c4
                                                           , c5
                                                           , c6
                                                           , c7
                                                           , c8
                                                           , c9
                                                           , c10)) AS UPV
            ) AS DATA
       WHERE PAR = 1
       GROUP BY COLUMNA;
```

Aunque no es más que un ejercicio, es de suponer que podrá ser un poco más eficiente, el hecho de validar la "paridad", que el hecho de numerarla.

También quizá podrías aplicar una query dinámica, para que el unpivot sea sólo por las columnas que te interesan, y probablemente mejore su eficiencia.

Comment: Hola Javi, esto no vale porque tengo que indicarle explícitamente las columnas que son pares. Me ocurre lo mismo con el ejemplo que propuso Luis, en el que también tengo que indicarle qué columnas son pares. Lo que yo quiero, y en mi solución así lo reflejé, es que el propio SQL discrimine aquellas columnas que son pares. Es que si se lo indico yo, para eso hago un SUM(column) por cada columna que me interesa y básicamente obtengo lo mismo con otra distribución.